# Использование мемкеша

Tags: php, memcached

Вот так у меня выводится информация

```
$count = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `blog`'), 0);
if ($count > 0) { 
    $req = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blog` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT " . $start . "," . $message); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req))
    {
        echo '<b>'.$row['name'].'</b> '.times($row['time']).'<br/>';
        if (mb_strlen($row['text']) > 149) {
            $text = mb_substr($row['text'], 0, 149);
            echo ''.$text.'...'; 
        }
        else {
            echo $row['text']; 
        }
        echo '<br/><a href="'.$home.'/admin/blog.php?view&amp;id='.$row['id'].'">подробнее</a><br/>
<a href="'.$home.'/admin/blog.php?edit&amp;id='.$row['id'].'"><input type="submit" value="редактировать запись"/></a>  <a href="'.$home.'/admin/blog.php?del&amp;id='.$row['id'].'"><input type="submit" value="удалить запись"/></a>
<div id="hr"></div>';
    }
    if ($count > $message) { 
        echo ''.pagenav('?', $start, $count, $message); 
    } 
}
else {
    echo 'Записи еще не созданы!'; 
}
```

А как правильно сделать вывод информации с использованием мемкеша? Чтобы информация кешировалась, допустим, на полчаса.

Comment: На будущее — форматируйте код, пожалуйста, иначе в этой мешанине ничего не видно. Вы же людям показываете, все-таки...

Answer (score 1):

```
// какой мемкеш используете непринципиально, 
// чуть отличаются параметры, принцип тот же остается. 
// Memcached чуть медленнее Memcache в синтетических тестах
$memcache = new Memcached();
// интервал кэширования
$cache_interval = 1800;     
//соединяемся
$memcache->addServer('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect to memcached");
//первый запрос
$query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `blog`';
//ключ, по которому будем искать этот запрос в мемкеше
$key = "blog_count";                   
$count = $memcache->get($key);         
if($count === false) { 
    // не нашли в мемкеше, берем из базы
    $count = mysql_result(mysql_query($query), 0);
    //складываем в мемкеш
    $memcache->set($key,$result,$cache_interval);  
} 
if($count>0) { 
    // второй запрос
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `blog` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT " . $start . "," . $message;
    // ключ для мемкеша этого запроса
    $key = md5('query'.$query);
    //ищем в мемкеше этот запрос
    $rows = $memcache->get($key);
    // нашли?
    if ($rows === false) { 
        // не нашли, читаем из базы в массив $rows
        $rows = array(); 
        $req = mysql_query($query); 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req))
        { 
            $rows[] = $rec;
        } 
        // пишем в мемкеш
        $memcache->set($key, $rows, $cache_interval); 
    }
    // работаем с массивом как раньше
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
       // используем $row как раньше...
...
```

ЗЫ писал в окне ответа, возможны ошибки

Comment: верно говорят, страницу тоже кэшировать можно. ну пусть будет как вариант работы с мемкешем...

Comment: А кто и как сбрасывает memcache при **изменении** данных в таблице blog ?

Comment: время :) это один из вариантов. простейший. да, можно изменять кэш при изменениях, но думается, что полчаса погоды не делают. все зависит от задачи.

Comment: Yura Ivanov, не работает. Записи не выводятся.

Comment: Поправил ошибку небольшую. В любом случае отлаживать вам. Проверяйте условия, сразу написанное редко когда работает сразу...

Comment: Мемкешед на сервере не работает.
Попробовал с мемкеш - записи не выводятся.

Comment: "время :) это один из вариантов. простейший."

Остается надеяться, что автор вопроса читает комментарии и задумывается при этом.

Comment: @avp судя по изначальному вопросу и речи о получасе, ТС видимо понимает, что на полчаса изменения будут заморожены для посетителей, которые ридонли. для авторов блога, которые захотят внести какие-либо изменения, такой подход естественно не годится. те, кто могут менять контент либо должны напрямую с базой работать (без кэша), либо придется на каждый update или delete в базе модифицировать кэш.

@vitagame не соединяется с сервером? или данные не сохраняются в кэше? то, что записи не выводятся - это уже итог, надо смотреть что происходит на каждом этапе (коннект, гет, сет...)

Comment: С мемкешом то соединяется.

$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");

А данные тупо не выводятся.

Answer (score 0):

По-индусски — например, так:

```
$mc = new Memcache;
$mc->connect(...);
...

$key = "blog/by-id[$start,$message]";
$html = $mc->get($key);
if ($html === false) {
    ob_start();
    $req = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blog` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT " . $start . "," . $message);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req)) {
        // ...
    }
    $html = ob_end_clean();
    $mc->set($key, $html);
}
```

Но это не код, а дрянь.

По-уму — разнести модели и представление, кэш фрагментов реализовать на уровне шаблонизатора, кэш данных — на уровне модели (миксина или декоратора). Чтобы не изобретать велосипед — взять уже готовый фреймворк, который все сам сделает.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы.


Например какой фреймворк?